# Some input isn't submitted in a very big form

Tags: php, html, forms

My problem is simple : i have a very big form with more than 300 fields in one page. after clicking submit some input in last wasn't submitted.

Is there any limitation for submit field in HTML?

Note: all fields is text type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be hitting the PHP `post_max_size` limit for your configuration (depending on size of input).

Try updating the value for `post_max_size` in your `php.ini` file or set the following in a `.htaccess` file:

```
#set max post size
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

If you are also including file upload in your form, you may also need to increase the upload limit and other input maximums:

```
upload_max_filesize=20M

#set max input size
post_max_size=20M

#set max input fields
max_input_vars=1000
```

Other issues could be:

- You're closing the form before the last input fields, and hence those fields are not being posted.
- You have HTML syntax issues in your form, which is causing some of the fields to be missed

Comment: Post some code up then. You won't get much help unless we can see what you're doing...

Comment: i work with Laravel framework and blade file more complex than i can send code.

Comment: your answer really help . please add `max_input_vars` to your answer to confirm this as right answer.